# Sidekiq "needs X11" in a rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sidekiq

I'm trying to use sidekiq in a project but have run into an unusual problem that makes no sense.
I've got multiple rails applications on my laptop, many of which are using sidekiq, and are running fine without any problems.

This application also uses sidekiq, and used to work however I'm not running into a problem. I've not touched the project for a while, but the only difference between now, and when it used to work is the upgrade from OS X Lion, to Mountain Lion. This however hasn't effected other projects, so I'm not sure what's going on. When I try to launch Sidekiq, I get an alert stating

```
To open "sidekiq," you need to install X11.
Would you like to install X11 now?
```

It's the standard Apple alert, however I don't understand why Sidekiq is supposedly trying to use X11, and why it isn't using it on my other projects?

I'm using

```
Rails 3.2.8
Ruby 1.9.3p125
Sidekiq 2.13.1
```

Any help would be really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it running. Turned out it wasn't an issue with Sidekiq, but rather ruby for some reason. After I updated ruby to 2.0.0 and fixed other gem issues, the app started up again and is now running. No idea what was going on but it's sorted :)